# FTP Webrequest Multiple Files without session close

Tags: c#, ftp, try-catch, ftpwebrequest

I need some help reworking this Method in such a way that it will not create a new FTP session for every file that is uploaded.

The variables are
server (IP or Hostname)
Dictionary(local file path, ftp server path) ex (c:/mydir/test.txt, \incoming)
PASV Use Passive Mode True/False
and the login/password to the FTP itself

I would like this to work in such a way.

1) Connect to server

2) For each file/path pair in dictionary, upload file

3) Disconnect from server

Is it possible to rewrite this method to accomplish that?

Also I know the try/catch should be better implemented,  I'd like to have a try/catch block for login to the FTP itself, then a try block for each file uploaded but I need to sort out the structure of the method first.

```
    protected static bool FtpStart(string server, Dictionary<string, string> FilePath, bool PASV, string login, string password)
    {
        foreach (var Current in FilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                //FileInfo for Filename passed.
                var ThisFile = new FileInfo(Current.Key);
                // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + server + Current.Value + ThisFile.Name);
                request.UsePassive = PASV;
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password);

                // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
                StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(Current.Key);
                byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
                sourceStream.Close();
                request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                response.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can KeepAlive your request to avoid connection closing

```
request.KeepAlive = true;
```

This will make a login only the first `FTPWebRequest`.

Then when you create the last `FTPWebRequest`

```
request.KeepAlive = false;
```

and it will close the connection when done.